# Image not showing on details screen

Tags: shoutem

I tried the tutorial on https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/my-first-extension/using-ui-toolkit

Previewed on Shoutem emulator but details.js is not showing the image. Any solution?

[details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXmum.jpg)

Comment: After finishing [Working With Data](http://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/my-first-extension/working-with-data), does it still fail to display images on details screens?

Comment: I am working slow only up to CLOUD STORAGE. it still fail to show the image. But once set the tag overlay color in the builder to less 30%. It works. Thanks. Will try and see how it works in Working With Data with the overlay set to theme default later.

Answer (score 0):

The `<Overlay>` tag is taking Builder defined values, in this case `Tag overlay color`. Setting it to a lower opacity (30%) and possibly to black, will resolve this. The image itself does load, it's just that the default overlay value is concealing it.

Comment: Great. Working.